# Get only checkbox custom field on a post Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

In Wordpress, I have pages with several custom fields (text, images, checkbox).

I want to get the keys of all the custom fields where type is checkbox.

how can i do that?

Comment: from the generated html? from the db entry for whatever form(s) have these fields in them?

Comment: can you post your code please?